# is there a new variable created each time in loop?

Tags: java

In the following example:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  int k;
}
```

1. Is it true that the loop body (that is, the statement "int k") will repeatedly be executed 10 times?
2. If this is the case, does that mean each time there will be a new variable k created? (because this "a type followed by a variable name" format is defined as creating a new variable in JAVA although the variable name keeps same)

Comment: No variable is "created". Just an int-sized space on the stack is reserved; and that same space is used over and over.

Comment: In this _particular_ example, if you were to actually compile and run it, there might not be any `k` variable, because the compiler would optimize it away, as it is not being used.

Comment: Regardless of what other people say below, the Java language doesn't specify how or when variables are allocated. 1) You can't say whether the body is executed 0 times, or 10 times because it doesn't *do* anything. The JVM is free to ignore the loop all together if it like. Should you have for instance printed something, then yes, it would have executed 10 times. 2) There's just *one* variable `k`. You don't need to care about when or how it is "created". What you need to know is a) it's bound to the loop body and can't be accessed outside, and b) the value will "reset" in each iteration.

Comment: @Tim the variable will always be there conceptuality, but it is possible the compiler doesn't store it in the memory.

Comment: @aioobe Regardless of what you may think, the [JVM Specification #2.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) does exactly that for local variables.

Comment: @EJP, see my comment below your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the memory for the variable exists in the method, not in the loop. The fact that you can only access `k` inside the loop is just done by the compiler.

If you were to change the code like this:

```
public class X
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           int k = i * 2;

           System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
}
```

Then run javap -c X to view the bytecode you would see:

```
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1          // i = 0
       2: iload_1
       3: bipush        10
       5: if_icmpge     25  // i < 10
       8: iload_1  
       9: iconst_2
      10: imul
      11: istore_2          // k = i * 2 < this is the key (see below)
      12: getstatic     
      15: iload_2           // this gets k (see below)
      16: invokevirtual #3                  
      19: iinc          1, 1   // i++
      22: goto          2
      25: return
```

`istore_2` stores the result of the calculation into the 2nd spot in the stack. `iload_2` gets the value that is in the 2nd spot on the stack. (You can see the descriptions of the instructions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html))

The stack exists at all times, think of it as an array that a method is able to access a certain part of.

Comment: Local variables are stored in the current *frame*, which is created when the method is entered. It doesn't exist at all times.

Comment: Looking at bytecode to explain the semantics of the Java language is a bit backward. This is highlighted by the fact that you had to *change* the Java code to support your explanation. Should you have kept the Java code posted in the question intact, the bytecode would have shown that the variable isn't allocated *at all*. The max locals for the method is the same with or without `int k;`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that the loop body (that is, the statement "int k") will repeatedly be executed 10 times?

It depends on exactly what you mean. The stack slot concerned will start being used for `k`, but it was allocated on method entry, not on loop entry.

> If this is the case, does that mean each time there will be a new variable k created? (because this "a type followed by a variable name" format is defined as creating a new variable in JAVA although the variable name keeps same).

The variable is created by the compiler. The address space it occupies is created on method entry, see above.

Contrary to certain claims in comments, this is fully specified by the [Java Virtual Machine Specification §2.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6):

> A new frame is created each time a method is invoked. A frame is destroyed when its method invocation completes, whether that completion is normal or abrupt (it throws an uncaught exception). Frames are allocated from the Java Virtual Machine stack (§2.5.2) of the thread creating the frame. Each frame has its own array of local variables (§2.6.1), its own operand stack (§2.6.2), and a reference to the run-time constant pool (§2.5.5) of the class of the current method.

Comment: EJP, this is a question about the Java language. Consequently, the only authoritative source is the Java Language Specification. To clarify what I mean: This question can obviously not be answered by looking at the CIL spec. This fact doesn't change even if I implement a Java -> CIL compiler! The translation from Java to JVM bytecode (or to CIL) can make an argument true by accident, or by chance and is not universal. Explaining the semantics of the Java language by pointing at JVM spec is *backwards reasoning*.

Answer (score 0):

Since the statement `int k` only declares a variable (allocates an int block) and does not define it, a new variable is not created every time.

Also, the scope of a local variable should be made as small as possible. Therefore, the only good way to declare the variable is inside the while loop.

If you would want to save clock cycles, when you initialise a variable e.g. `int k = 3;`, to save extra clock time you can declared outside the while loop thus increasing the scope of the variable. In this case, the variable won't be initialised every time.

Comment: `I raised up this question only for assuring myself with clear, consistent expression of JAVA language itself, but not for any practical reasons. As the previous answers put, if we check the byte codes we can know there is no new variable or space allocated, but this kind of format/expression (I mean, the statement "int k" actually does nothing during the last 9 loops) logically is confusing to a newbie like me.`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the variable `k` is created 10 times.

But this doesn't mean anything for performance, since the Java compiler will know that the use of these 10 variables do not overlap. Therefore, it may reuse the same memory storage (or a register) for it.

So don't be afraid of creating many variables, it's ok. Be more afraid of creating objects with `new`. But even then will the compiler optimize some of them away.

Comment: No, the variable was created once, by the compiler, and the frame slot that it occupies was created once when the method was entered.